# Git repo won't get garbage collected after reset --hard

Tags: git, bitbucket

I just started playing with Git and was wondering about one specific case:

I made a heavy commit, by mistake, and even worse I pushed it to the remote server.

Now I'm trying to get things back to the way they were, using `git reset --hard v1.0` and `git push -f origin master`.

After doing that things seem OK, but when I look at the repo file size, it's still as big as my wrong commit. Even if I try **git gc** to garbage collect, I have no success. What should I do in that case, if I want to make a destructive change, on purpose?

Any tip is appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to [rewrite history](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html): http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/

Comment: @miku: no, git reset might be enough. Even with history rewriting the reflog is still in effect.

Answer (score 3):

You may have altered the history, what you have not cleared, however, is the reflog.

If you type:

```
git reflog
```

you will see that your "big commit" is still there. By default, all entries are kept for 30 days if unreachable, 90 days if reachable (via history).

You can try and use `git reflog --expire-unreachable=1.minute` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to expire the reflog of the branch you rewound and the HEAD reflog, then gc can collect the now unreachable commits:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now HEAD <branches which contained said commit>
git gc
```

The reflog is Git's safety mechanism which keeps track of previous branch states so you don't immediately lose data when issuing an incorrect git reset command or running a bogus rebase, funky whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to clone again the repository. However, it can take a long time if your repository is big. To remove the files without cloning again the project, you can wait a certain time to git automatically remove the files or force it using the following commands:

```
git reflog expire --all --expire-unreachable=0
git repack -A -d
git prune
```

Answer (score 1):

I repeated the steps I said at the beginning, made a new clone of the repo, and it's fine now. Thank you guys!